# Получить координаты полигона на svg

Tags: jquery, svg, javascript

Как узнать координаты svg полигона относитульно body например? Ну или хотя бы относительно краёв svg. С объектом типа rect проблем нет, jQuery offset определяет корректно смещение.
С полигоном это не работает, библиотека jquery svgdom подключена.
Есть ли вообще возможность получить либо координаты центра, либо координаты прямоугольника, в который вписан полигон. Пробовал getBBox но он по координате Y странные значения выдаёт

Comment: @Deadik, вы пример какой-нибудь набросайте.  
Ответ дать проще, имея перед глазами тестовые данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@VenZell](/users/13336/venzell) пока размещал нужные куски кода на фидле разобрался с проблемой. offset там корректно отрабатывал, однако всё это было на ready повешено, а svg несмотря на то что является xml не воспринимается некоторыми браузерами как элемент dom и поэтому одним из основных шагов к решению задачи было повесить на onLoad обработку svg